# Redirect Django not working and not redirecting

Tags: python-3.x, django, redirect, django-forms

views.py:

```
def showLoginPage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
            if 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' not in body_unicode:
                body = json.loads(body_unicode)
                user_obj = AuthenticateUser()
                user_obj.validate_user(body)
                c={}
                c.update(csrf(request))
                return redirect('http://abchostname/mainPage/')
                # return redirect('/mainPage') This is another url which i want to redirect after 
                # successful login
        except Exception as exe:
            print("Inside Exception : ",exe)
            raise
    else:
        print("Inside else {}".format(request.method))

    return render(request, 'login.html')

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def showMainPage(request):
    return render(request, 'mainPage.html')
```

I want to redirect after a successful login, I see the login is getting successful and it is hitting by backend correctly as well.

```
 [07/Jul/2020:06:59:29 +0000] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2082 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
 [07/Jul/2020:06:59:36 +0000] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2081 "http://abchostname/login/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
 [07/Jul/2020:06:59:36 +0000] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 306 "http://abchostname/login/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
```

In the third option 302 status code is shown which means it is redirecting. I need some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

To perform a redirect, its better to give named urls and acccess url with the name,

```
return redirect('main-page')
```

redirect() will try to use its given arguments to reverse a URL.

```
path('/main-page/', showMainPage, name='main-page')
```

Even if giving the url directly, dont give the full url, give a relative url like:

```
 return redirect('/mainPage/')
```

Read More: [https://realpython.com/django-redirects/#:~:text=Django%20Redirects%3A%20A%20Super%20Simple%20Example,-In%20Django%2C%20you&text=Just%20call%20redirect()%20with,then%20return%20from%20your%20view.&text=Assuming%20this%20is%20the%20main,to%20%2Fredirect%2Dsuccess%2F%20.](https://realpython.com/django-redirects/#:%7E:text=Django%20Redirects%3A%20A%20Super%20Simple%20Example,-In%20Django%2C%20you&text=Just%20call%20redirect()%20with,then%20return%20from%20your%20view.&text=Assuming%20this%20is%20the%20main,to%20%2Fredirect%2Dsuccess%2F%20.)

Comment: I tried "  return redirect('/mainPage/') " this option and other option as well. But still it is not working. I see from backend it is getting redirected but in the browser the page doesn't get redirected. I am not sure if there is the problem in caching or something else!!!